# Share interest, Unique ranking

Tags: idioms

1. What does "**sharing interest**" means?

Ex) Managers often give the highest rankings to workers who **share the manager's interest** outside of work

2. What does **unique ranking** means?

Ex) Some companies require managers to give **unique rankings** to the workers they supervise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "Sharing interest" is not a particular phrase: read it literally: both have some interest in common.
2. Don't know what "unique ranking" means - it's not a phrase either. My guess is that it means that the managers are required to rank their staff (put them in order of merit) in such a way that each one has a different ranking: there are no ties with two people given the same ranking.